# Beer that's slightly out of date

Tags: taste, history

I've got a case of beer, which is Rivet Beer. Each can is 330 mL, & 4.7%/1.2 standard drinks. They ran out of date on 13 November 2015, & it's been in a cupboard the entire time, room temperature. Are the cans safe to drink? I'm not concerned about bad taste or anything, I just don't want to get sick. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Should not be a problem healthwise, taste could be a little different but as it was stored in a can it was protected from sunlight.